# What, if anything, is the advantage of \bigskip and friends over \vspace?

Tags: macros, spacing

What are the advantages to using `\bigskip`, `\medskip`, and `\smallskip` instead of just using `\vspace{somelength}`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Flexibility.

```
\show\bigskip
```

reveals that `\bigskip` expands to `\vspace{\bigskipamount}` so in terms of functionality, there's no difference.  However, if after typing a 110 page thesis, you realise that the limit for length set by your university is 100 pages, then simply redefining `\bigskipammount` might get you your extra 10 pages in one fell swoop, rather than having to go through and considering each individual `\vspace` and remembering why it was there.

In general, a good rule is that commands should carry contextual information.  So even though `\(\vec{x}\)` and `\(\overline{x}\)` might look the same, `\(\vec{x}\)` should always be used for vectors and for nothing else.  So that when that Big Shot Journal says "House style is that all vectors are purple with yellow dots", a simple `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\color{purple with yellow dots}#1}` does the trick *without* messing up any of the rest of the document.

---

**Edit:** (in response to vanden's request in the comments)

Of course, `\bigskipamount` is a *length* and in TeX, lengths can be a bit complicated: they don't have to be exact measurements but can include a little flexibility.  Examining `latex.ltx` reveals that, unless further modified, `\bigskipamount` (and the others) are defined to be:

```
\newskip\smallskipamount \smallskipamount=3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\newskip\medskipamount   \medskipamount  =6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\newskip\bigskipamount   \bigskipamount =12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt
```

Hopefully, the meaning of the syntax is clear.  Thus if you are redefining `\bigskipamount` then it's good practice to also include a little flexibility.

If this is new to someone, it's worth knowing that such lengths are called [*rubber* lengths](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Rubber/Stretching_lengths) and the extra bit is known as [*glue*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#TeX_boxes_and_glue_overview) so those are the words to look out for in the documentation.  (Hope I've gotten that bit right; certainly those two words are *associated* with this concept.)

**Moral of the Story**: Flexibility's what you need.

(Probably only people of my generation who grew up in Britain will have a hope of getting the reference there)

Comment: Typo: `\bigskipamount` (only one 'm')

Comment: Thanks!  That's one problem with these conjoined macros: it's hard to spell-check them.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, but I wish I could give another upvote for the second paragraph.

Comment: What Mark said.

Comment: @vanden: is that acceptable?  I figured it wasn't really the place for a full treatise on rubber lengths, but that it was sufficiently close to put in a pointer that they are involved.

Comment: @Andrew Perfectly. Have a badge!

Comment: @vanden: Thanks!  (You're not a Goon Show fan by any chance?)

Comment: @Andrew: Love Sellers. Not familiar enough with the Goon Show to catch the reference. <geek shame>

Comment: @vanden: I thought I'd reply with a link to enlighten you and then discovered that the best advice I can give is to type "Goon Show have a" into google and look at the auto-completion suggestion!  (Then click "search" and click on one of the links to find out more.)