# \section eventually calls \@startsection with \@plus and \@minus. What's going on?

Tags: macros, sectioning, glue

Can anybody explain to me what this

```
\section
```

code does in the following definition:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                   {-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                   {1.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

In particular, what does `@` do, and why aren't `\@minus` and `\@plus` evaluated immediately but, on the contrary, given both?

Comment: If I understood your question, it's probably a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/134574

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89997/82917

Comment: In class files or sty-files `@` is a letter, but normally it something else (other). That means internally there can be command names like `\@startsection`. These can only be used internally. The command `\@plus` expands to `plus` and `\@minus` to `minus`.

Comment: Related: [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's weird. `\section` in the regular use-case can have any of the following 3 input styles:

```
\section{<title>}
\section[<ToC title>]{<title>}
\section*{<title>}
```

However, it's not clear how *any* of these relate to its definition (in [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co)):

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                   {-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                   {1.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

That's because `\section` uses `\@startsection` that actually defines a large number of spacing and formatting parameters. In fact, `\@startsection` itself is just an intermediary macro that grabs only 6 arguments (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co))

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
```

before handing it over to `\@ssect` or `\@dblarg`, depending on whether you used `\section` or `\section*`. That's why it's odd - `\section` is defined to not take any arguments, yet we can supply it with arguments; that's because the arguments are taken and processed by secondary macros contained within `\section` and deeper.

For more detail about what each argument in `\@startsection` does, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764).

---

Specifically, the spacing arguments passed to `\@startsection` contain [glue-like lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/5764) which, in general, have the following format

```
<lengthA> <plus> <lengthB> <minus> <lengthC>
```

Since the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) defines `\@plus`/`\@minus` to be `plus`/`minus`, users often mix these as needed. In short the format suggests that the resulting length could be anything between

```
<lengthA> + <lengthB>
```

(at maximum) and

```
<lengthA> - <lengthC>
```

(at minimum). Specific to the 4th argument of `\@startsection`, the (vertical) **beforeskip** for a `\section` could be as small as `2.3ex` (`2.5ex - .2ex`) or as large as `3.5ex` (`2.5ex + 1ex`)<sup>*</sup>. Similarly, the **afterskip**  ranges between `1.3ex` and `1.5ex` (`1.3ex + .2ex`). The actual value used depends on the other contents used to fill the page (since this glue/stretch is *vertical*).

<sub><sup>*</sup> Note that `\@startsection`'s 4th argument sign (positive or negative) is removed from the length calculation and actually denotes the use/suppression of paragraph indentation following a `\section`. See [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) for details.</sub>