# Understanding what contour package does

Tags: color, contour

In `contour` package, the macro `\con@put` is defined as:

```
\newcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \rlap{\hskip#1\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
```

But if one changes that `\rlap` to `\llap`, then you no longer get contour. For instance, try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \llap{\hskip#1\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\colorbox{black}{This text is not visible
\contour{white}{but this is.}}
\end{document}
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Why this does not work? What is the special effect of that `\rlap` that makes contour? and if one decides to go with `\llap` instead `\rlap` in the example above, what changes are required so you still get contour?

Comment: `\llap` would print the box on the wrong side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `contour` sets the text many times: First the text is set in the specified color several times, slightly moved horizontally and vertically. Then the "inner" part is printed in black. The result is a "contour" in the specified color. Changing the background color makes it a little visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{This text is not visible
\contour{white}{but this is.}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The default of package `contour` is to put 16 copies in the specified color first. The star form uses 32 copies, or the number of copies can be specified in the optional argument of `\contour`.

Changing `\rlap` to `\llap` puts the first text prints to the left instead to the right. The final text in black is put to the right, invisible with black background. Again with changed background to red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \llap{\hskip#1\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{This text is not visible
\contour{white}{but this is.}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \llap]

---

Just for fun: An alternative to `contour` is package `pdfrender`, which can set the contour using PDF features of vector fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{black}{This text is not visible
\textpdfrender{
  TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
  StrokeColor=white,
  LineWidth=.25pt,
}{but this is.}}

\colorbox{red}{This text is not visible
\textpdfrender{
  TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
  FillColor=red,
  StrokeColor=white,
  LineWidth=.25pt,
}{but this is.}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result pdfrender]

Also package `contour` can use this PDF feature, if option package option `outlines` is given. Then `\con@put` is not used.

Comment: `pdfrender` does not work with `xetex`. If you are using `\pdfliteral` primitive of PDFTeX for this, then you can use `\special{pdf:code ...}` for `dvipdfmx` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using Heiko's explanation, the answer to my last question would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\con@put[3]{%
  \llap{\raisebox{#2}[0pt]{#3}\hskip-\dimexpr\wd0+#1\relax}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setbox0\hbox{but this is.}

\colorbox{black}{This text is not visible
\contour{white}{but this is.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of so doing?

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64759/4427 If you're interested into understanding `\rlap` and `\llap` it's very good.

Comment: @egreq: I know what `\rlap` and `\llap` does. I was just confused because of the strange behavior of `e-tex`; please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191222/llap-mystery-with-tex-xet