# Contour AND drop shadow for text

Tags: xetex, shadows, contour

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{.4pt}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
\shadowoffsetx{0pt}
\shadowoffsety{-.2pt}
\shadowcolor{red}
    \resizebox*{100mm}{!}{\shadowtext{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{the text}}}}
\end{document}
```

I need to add a contour to the text as well, but it won't compile no matter where I put in the `\contour{}` command. Please note that I use xelatex.

Help?

Comment: Related: [Understanding what contour package does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191202/124842) , it works also with xelatex. Where do you want to use `\contour` ?

Comment: @Bobyandbob, around `the text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{.4pt}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
\shadowcolor{red}
\shadowoffsetx{0pt}
\shadowoffsety{-.2pt}
\resizebox*{100mm}{!}{\contour{blue}{\shadowtext{\textbf{\uppercase{the test}}}}}
\end{document}
```

Works for me. It complains, but apparently still renders the result you're looking for (I think).

[image]

EDIT: To be clear, run

`xelatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error <yourfile>`

to compile.

Comment: Hurm, `xelatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error mwe.tex` gives me no output files?

EDIT: It appears it gives me `mwe.log` and `mwe.aux` but no PDF files.

Comment: EDIT 2: Appears I can just plow through with plain `xelatex`. Odd.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do `\shadowtext{\contour{...` to get it to work. The other way round `relax`ed the offsety parameter, leaving it undefined for `shadowtext` after `contour` did its multiple font shape iterations.

Removed `resizebox` as well since it pixellated a lot, so used scaling instead, for smoother lines.

[image: base of T]

General font effects are possible with those two packages:

[image: Example font effects]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Scale=3]
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{shadowtext}


\begin{document}
\contourlength{1.4pt}
\shadowcolor{blue}
\shadowoffsetx{1.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{1.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[32]{yellow}{%
\textbf{\uppercase{the test}}
}%
}%

\bigskip

\contourlength{0.4pt}
\color{yellow}
\shadowcolor{blue}
\shadowoffsetx{0.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{0.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[24]{red}{%
\textbf{\uppercase{the test}}
}%
}%

\bigskip

\contourlength{0.8pt}
\color{Magenta}
\shadowcolor{blue!40}
\shadowoffsetx{4.52pt}
\shadowoffsety{2.52pt}
\Huge
\shadowtext{%
\contour[24]{red}{%
some text
}%
}%


\end{document}
```