# TikZ: Define a style of node that puts halo/contour around text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, contour

How put halo around text using the contour package as suggested [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18473/9789) in many nodes by defining a style?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[outline]{contour} %halo around text
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text
\contourlength{1.2pt}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[halo text node/.style={circle, draw, pattern=north east lines}]

    \node [halo text node] {\contour{white}A};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: MWE result]

What I want is to include an option for the `tikzpicture` in a form similar to `halo text node/.style{...,text=\contour{white}}` instead of using `\contour{white}{...}` inside every node.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18522/2388.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do not answer your question (because I don't know how to apply `\contour` to the node content) but gives you an alternative approach to define `contour text` style that takes the node content as parameter.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.2pt}
\tikzset{
  contour text/.style={node contents={\contour{white}{#1}}},
  halo text node/.style={circle, draw, pattern=north east lines}
}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\node[halo text node, contour text=ABC];
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- This do not work with XeLaTeX for me.
- Another possibility is to not use `contour` package [but](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191202) `pdfrender`, or to redefine the action of contour in pure TikZ (move the text multiple times around with different color before to print it).