# How to fill text with bands of colour in tikz and keep normal text positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to colour letters/words/strings with multiple bands of colour per string. It would look like the flag of Ireland/Russia/Germany is behind the text. I would like my final function to let me use the text as if it were normal (i.e, without a larger bounding box).

I've added an outlined sample which works as I want, which is like normal text. I also want it to be outlined like this but that seems easier anyway.

[image: sample of outline vs. sample of rainbow text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sample}{\bfseries sample}
\textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.2pt,
    LineJoinStyle=1, 
    FillColor=pink
}
\sample \ works well with other text.%
\newlength{\samplewidth}
\newlength{\sampleheight}
\newlength{\colourheight}
\newlength{\bandYone}
\newlength{\bandYtwo}
\newlength{\bandYthree}
\newlength{\bandYfour}
{\setlength{\samplewidth}{\widthof{\sample}}
\setlength{\sampleheight}{\totalheightof{\sample}}
\setlength{\colourheight}{.3333333333\sampleheight}
\setlength{\bandYone}{-.5\sampleheight}
\setlength{\bandYtwo}{\bandYone}
\addtolength{\bandYtwo}{\colourheight}
\setlength{\bandYthree}{\bandYtwo}
\addtolength{\bandYthree}{\colourheight}
\setlength{\bandYfour}{\bandYthree}
\addtolength{\bandYfour}{\colourheight}

\framebox{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=A]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1, transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=B]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=C]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,thick, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\path[path fading=A,fill=red,fit fading=false] (-.5\samplewidth,\bandYone) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYtwo);
\path[path fading=B,fill=green,fit fading=false] (-.5\samplewidth,\bandYtwo) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYthree);
\path[path fading=C,fill=yellow,fit fading=false](-.5\samplewidth,\bandYthree) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYfour);
%\path[draw=blue] (-10,-1) rectangle (10,0);
%\path[draw=red] (-10,0) rectangle (10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
} %Framebox
}
does not work well as it adds space around the text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use epsf to include graphics in latex in any document written since the 1980s, similarly `pslatex` (which I wrote) should not be used this century.

Comment: I'm not even sure how that ended up in my preamble. I think it was included with the example I originally found, but then I didn't know whether I needed it or not. Thx for the tip, will delete.

Comment: copying random preambles is a really bad habit, it just leads to convoluted code and hard to debug clashes, Always start from an _empty_ preamble and only add packages that you need in the document.

Comment: I got rid of the random stuff I had in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key to keep the normal text position of a tikz node text ist to use `baseline` as an option in `tikzpicture`. To reduce the overall space use `inner sep` and `outer sep` as you like. You can also use different seperation for `x`and `y` if you want.

Based on the answer from hpekristiansen I've addeded the possibility to define any amount of colors larger or equal than two. It makes use of the `colormap` definition from [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). You can use existing ones or define your own.

Contour with [`pdfrender`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfrender) seems not to work, so I used [`contour`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/contour).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{contour}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={ShadingColor}{color=(blue),color=(green),color=(yellow),color=(orange),color=(red)}}

% \TextShade{<colormap>}{<number of colors>}{<contour color>}{<text>}
\newcommand{\TextShade}[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \foreach \c in {1,2,...,#2}{
        \pgfplotscolormapaccess[1:#2]{\c}{#1}
        \definecolor{colortemp}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}
        \ifnum\c=1
            \node[colortemp, anchor=base, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=.5pt, outer sep=0pt,draw=black] (n) at (0,0) {\contour{#3}{#4}};
        \else
            \pgfmathparse{1-(\c-1)/#2}
            \clip let \p1=(n.south west), \p2=(n.north east), in (n.south west) rectangle (\x2,\y1+\pgfmathresult*\y2-\pgfmathresult*\y1);     
            \node[colortemp, anchor=base, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=.5pt, outer sep=0pt] {#4};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

~\\\Large
This \TextShade{ShadingColor}{50}{black}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} is a test.\\
This \TextShade{viridis}{3}{black}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} is a test.\\ % viridis, hot, ...
This \TextShade{viridis}{3}{blue}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} is a test.\\
This \TextShade{viridis}{3}{green}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} is a test.\\
This abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz is a test.\\

\end{document}
```

[image: multi color text]

For another way to shade letters you can also take a look at [Rainbow-colored one letter with tikz and xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344260/rainbow-colored-one-letter-with-tikz-and-xcolor).

Comment: This approach is really nice in that there is less code per piece of text. I wonder if it would be possible to make the text outlined, as in my first sample. When I tried to combine ```\pdftextrender``` with your function it fills the outline with the same colours, as opposed to black for example. Ideally the parameter for linewidth is measured the same as in ```\pdftextrender```

Comment: I've edited my answer. `pdfrender` seems not to work, so I used the `contour` package.

Comment: ``contour`` sure makes the text bad :( no copy-paste or search cause there are 12 of everything. Also you can't adjust the line thickness. I wonder what route someone could go to get the best of all worlds. I read in the link that "If you are using ``\pdfliteral`` primitive of ``PDFTeX``, then you can use ``\special{pdf:code ...}`` for ``dvipdfmx`` driver." Could something like this work here?
[1] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191201/understanding-what-contour-package-does

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You are adding space tokens from ends of lines, each one I commented out with `%%%`  I also set `\fboxsep` to 0pt to get a tighter box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsf} 
\usepackage{svg}
%\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sample}{\bfseries sample}
\textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.2pt,
    LineJoinStyle=1, 
    FillColor=pink
}
\sample \ works well with other text.%
\newlength{\samplewidth}
\newlength{\sampleheight}
\newlength{\colourheight}
\newlength{\bandYone}
\newlength{\bandYtwo}
\newlength{\bandYthree}
\newlength{\bandYfour}
{\setlength{\samplewidth}{\widthof{\sample}}
\setlength{\sampleheight}{\totalheightof{\sample}}
\setlength{\colourheight}{.3333333333\sampleheight}
\setlength{\bandYone}{-.5\sampleheight}
\setlength{\bandYtwo}{\bandYone}
\addtolength{\bandYtwo}{\colourheight}
\setlength{\bandYthree}{\bandYtwo}
\addtolength{\bandYthree}{\colourheight}
\setlength{\bandYfour}{\bandYthree}
\addtolength{\bandYfour}{\colourheight}


\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\framebox{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=A]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1, transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%%%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=B]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%%%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=C]
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,transparent!0, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip] (-.5\samplewidth,-.5\sampleheight) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,.5\sampleheight);
\node[scale=1,thick, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\sample};
\path[path fading=A,fill=red,fit fading=false] (-.5\samplewidth,\bandYone) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYtwo);
\path[path fading=B,fill=green,fit fading=false] (-.5\samplewidth,\bandYtwo) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYthree);
\path[path fading=C,fill=yellow,fit fading=false](-.5\samplewidth,\bandYthree) rectangle (.5\samplewidth,\bandYfour);
%\path[draw=blue] (-10,-1) rectangle (10,0);
%\path[draw=red] (-10,0) rectangle (10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%%%
}%%% %Framebox
}
does not work well as it adds space around the text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sample}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[orange, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (n) {sample};
\clip let \p1 =(n.north east), in (n.south west) rectangle (\x1,0.5*\y1);          
\node[green, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {sample};
\clip let \p1 =(n.north east), in (n.south west) rectangle (\x1,0.2*\y1);          
\node[red, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {sample};
\end{tikzpicture}}
~\\
This \sample{} is a test.\\
This sample is a test.\\
\end{document}
```

[image: Text with multi colored word]

Edit: With arguments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sample}[5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[#3, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (n) {sample};
\clip let \p1 =(n.north east), in (n.south west) rectangle (\x1,#5*\y1);          
\node[#2, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {sample};
\clip let \p1 =(n.north east), in (n.south west) rectangle (\x1,#4*\y1);          
\node[#1, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {sample};
\end{tikzpicture}}
~\\
This \sample{red}{green}{orange}{0.2}{0.5} is a test.\\
This sample is a test.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the command accept the list of colours.. and for it to accept an arbitrary amount? That would be super.

Comment: Yes - see edit: It all depends on what you need - in how many different situations you want to use it. I also like the use of a `colormap` from @mais.

Comment: @TheRealDre accept the answer if it solved your problem :D