# Using skip (glue) with pgfmath (truncating plus/minus parts from a glue length)?

Tags: lengths, pgfmath

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\tlen}
\newlength{\tlenB}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tlen}{2cm}
\typeout{check 1, tlen is: \the\tlen}
\pgfmathsetlength{\tlenB}{2cm}
\typeout{check 1, tlenB is: \the\tlenB}

\setlength{\tlen}{2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\typeout{check 2, tlen is: \the\tlen}
\pgfmathsetlength{\tlenB}{2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\typeout{check 2, tlenB is: \the\tlenB}

\end{document}
```

It results with this output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
...
check 1, tlen is: 56.9055pt
check 1, tlenB is: 56.9055pt
check 2, tlen is: 56.9055pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `p' or `pl' (in '2cm plus 2pt minus 
1pt').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 ...hsetlength{\tlenB}{2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

So, apparently `\pgfmathsetlength` (or `pgfmath` in general?) cannot handle glue-type lengths, in particular the `plus` and `minus` parts.

What option do I have in using <s>glue-type length</s> skip with `pgfmath`? If nothing better is possible, then I'd settle for the fixed part only (i.e. I could live with the `plus`/`minus` stretchable/shrinkable parts being truncated)...

(Note to self: good intro on glues here: [What is glue stretching?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64756/what-is-glue-stretching))

Comment: The buzzword is a **skip** (as opposed to glue-type length) and pgfmath obtains a single number as a result of a math operation. Hence you can't set a skip with stretch/shrink values. It is not meant to be a generic length setter.

Comment: LaTeX lengths defined with `\newlength` are rubber lengths (skips, in TeXbook terminology), while `\pgfmathsetlength` is only able to cope with rigid lengths (`\dimen` registers). Unfortunate clash of terms.

Comment: Thank you both @percusse and @ egreg for the comments, great as reference; I tried to edit the post a bit as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Look at how `\pgfmathsetlength` works (from `pgfmathcalc.code.tex`):

```
\def\pgfmathsetlength#1#2{%
  \expandafter\pgfmath@onquick#2\pgfmath@%
  {%
    % Ok, quick version:
    \begingroup%
      \pgfmath@selectfont%
      #1#2\unskip%
    \expandafter\endgroup%
    \expandafter#1\the#1\relax%  
  }%
  {%
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \ifpgfmathmathunitsdeclared%
      #1\pgfmathresult mu\relax%
    \else%
      #1\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
    \fi%
  }%
  \ignorespaces%
}
```

The “quick version” is chosen when the second argument starts with `+` (see section 88.3 in the manual), which is not the case here. In the “normal case”, the expression is evaluated as usual and turned into a decimal number (meaning unit points); if the original expression had `mu` units, also the final setting will be with `mu` units.

In your case,

```
\pgfmathparse{2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

is tried, which is illegal and throws

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `p' or `pl' (in '2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt').
```

This doesn't happen with

```
\pgfmathparse{\tlen}
```

which would be executed by `\pgfmathsetlength{\tlenB}{\tlen}` because rubber lengths (`\skip`) are coerced to rigid lengths (`\dimen`) when found in the latter context.

In plain TeX terms, if you do

```
\newskip\tlen
\newdimen\temp

\tlen=1pt plus 2pt minus 3pt % a silly value just for example
\temp=\tlen
```

the `\dimen` register `\tlen` is set to `1pt`; the stretch and shrink components are discarded.

In conclusion, `\pgfmathsetlength` works with *rigid lengths*. To the contrary, LaTeX's `\newlength` allocates a *rubber length* register.

A case of unfortunate terminology conflict. A rule of thumb is remembering that rubber lengths have no use in TikZ pictures (unless text is being typeset in them, but it's a different matter), whereas in text mode rubber lengths are as much used as rigid ones.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this by accident while writing the question, so I better note it down: by replacing the below snippet in the code above:

```
...
\setlength{\tlen}{2cm plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\typeout{check 2, tlen is: \the\tlen}
\pgfmathsetlength{\tlenB}{\tlen}
\typeout{check 2, tlenB is: \the\tlenB}
...
```

... the code will compile without errors, with the following output:

```
check 1, tlen is: 56.9055pt
check 1, tlenB is: 56.9055pt
check 2, tlen is: 56.9055pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt
check 2, tlenB is: 56.9055pt
```

... which means that as long as a glue length is set via `\setlength`, such a length can (apparently) be used as an argument to `\pgfmathsetlength`, and it will pass - with the `plus` and `minus` truncated from the `\pgfmathsetlength` variable.