# How to set the spacing before and after of section headings to a fixed value of 1.5cm?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

In this code, i want the spacing before and after of my `section`, `subsection`, and `subsubsection` headings to be exactly `1.5cm` regardless of the font size or my line spacing. **How can i do this?**
I know that this question has been asked before several times on this site but **I want a package-free solution.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Foo Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

## Edit

I know that the spacing before, say, section headings is controlled by the code below, but when I enter `-1.5cm` instead of `-3.25ex`, the vertical space before the heading doesn't become exactly 1.5cm on the output. **Why?**

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Are you use `-1.5cm \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex`?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a package? There is no real difference between the code coming from a package and the code you are writing into your document. It could even be much more trouble without a package.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I do, but the space is not exact on the output.

Comment: @Sisabe because you are using stretchable glue

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes. I am scared of side effects of packages, especially the `titlesec` package.

Comment: @Sisabe: When use add the `\@plus` and `\@minus`, you allow for `1.5cm` to increase by `1ex` or decrease by `.2ex` (see [What is glue stretching?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/5764)). If you use *only* `-1.5cm`, you should get a fixed skip of `1.5cm` from the baseline of the last paragraph to the top of the baseline of the section title.

Answer (score 2):

The package free solution, just using another document class ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,emulatestandardclasses]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
    beforeskip=-1.5cm,%
    afterskip=1.5cm%
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Foo Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm talking about the `book` class, not `scrbook`.

Comment: @Sisabe I saw that, that's why there is the smiley and the option `emulatestandardclasses` to make no visual difference as everything is taken over from the standardclasses.