# parskip options

Tags: spacing

What is the difference in effect/appearance of a typeset document between
the commands set in the preamble:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus.05ex minus.05ex}
```

and  simply `\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}` ?

Comment: Are we talking about a special document class? Or just `article`?

Comment: might be informative: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64759/34258

Answer (score 2):

In your first case there is some flexibility in the vertical spacing, where the space is normally `1.5ex` but this can stretch or shrink a little if necessary for a best fit on the page. In the second case the spacing if fixed at `1.5ex`.