# Difference in theorem spacing between article and amsart

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsart

I defined a new theorem environment style, which I called "slanted." When I use the default "article" style, then everything looks great. However, whenever I use "amsart", the new theorem style is not separated by any space from above or below. Does anyone know **why that is the case**? Below you can see both pieces of code and their outputs (for comparison, I also included a definition style environment, which in both cases looks fine)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{times,newtxmath}

\newtheoremstyle{slanted}
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\slshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {0.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %         \newline = linebreak
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{slanted}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{de}{Definition}

\begin{document}

Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.
\begin{theorem}
Mathematicians seek out patterns.
\end{theorem}

   Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.
\begin{de}
Mathematicians seek out patterns.
\end{de}

Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.

\end{document}
```

The output of this code looks as follows:

[image]

Whereas if I use "amsart" instead of "article"

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{times,newtxmath}

\newtheoremstyle{slanted}
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\slshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {0.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %         \newline = linebreak
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{slanted}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{de}{Definition}

\begin{document}

Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.
\begin{theorem}
Mathematicians seek out patterns.
\end{theorem}

   Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.
\begin{de}
Mathematicians seek out patterns.
\end{de}

Mathematicians resolve the truth or falsity of conjectures by mathematical proof.

\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the "Thm head font" line by

```
   {\bfseries\showthe\topsep}% Thm head font
```

then with `article` class it reports in the `.log` file:

```
> 10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 6.0pt.
```

whereas `amsart` gives

```
> 2.44998pt plus 2.44998pt.
```

This shows that the two document classes have made different decisions about the value of `\topsep`.  Instead you can replace your style definition by something like:

```
\newtheoremstyle{slanted}
  {10pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}%   Space above
  {10pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}%   Space below
  {\slshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {0.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %         \newline = linebreak
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
```

so the separation is specified explicitly.

In `amsart`, the `\topsep` is set to `\smallskipamount` with is a quarter of `\bigskipamount` = `.7\baselineskip plus .7\baselineskip`.

For `article.cls` with the `12pt` option, the value is set in `size12.clo` under the setting for `\@listi`.

Comment: Dr Swann, thank you for your answer! So I understand now that the value of \topsep is just different for these two different styles. Would you mind explaining what "10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 6.0pt" means? I understand that it will give me the spacing that I want (since that is how it is defined in the article style), but I would like to understand what these numbers mean exactly (for example, what does 10pt represent? 4pt? etc)

Comment: This is a glue specification: make the space `10pt` but allow it to stretch by `4pt` or reduce by `6pt`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/15925

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help, I think I understand it now!