# Why does \vfill not put the text at the bottom of this page?

Tags: tables

I am using a \vfill expecting all the text on the last page to be at the bottom.
I don't understand why its not.
Is it because the table is a float or something.
Hope this is not a silly question. I;ll remove it if it is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.7}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.7,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0.0,0.5,0.0}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{White}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vfill

{
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Change History Rev B and C} % title of Table
%\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{|| l | l | c | p{8cm} ||} \hline

 \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Revision} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Comments}          \\ \hline 
\hline
A.N.Other & PB1 & 16MAR2017 & blah blah \\ \hline
A.N.Other & PB2 & 29MAR2017 & blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah. \\ \hline
A.N.Other & PB3 & 10MAY2017 & blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah. \\ \hline 


A.N.Other & PC2 & 17NOV2017 & blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah temp relationship \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\tiny
\begin{verbatim}
Stored in dev:/git/example

latex source file is:  dd.tex
with sub directory images_sw_doc/ containing graphics files:

\end{verbatim}

Last Page.

typeset in {\Huge \LaTeX} \today.

\end{document}
```

Comment: As Colas answers, place an `\mbox` before the `\vfill`.  The way to think of it logically is that the `\vfill` needs something (call it an anchor) against which to push.  The `\mbox{}` provides such an anchor.  For a `\vfill` applied at the bottom of the page, you would want the anchor *after* the `\vfill`.  Without the anchor, the `\vfill` is like a spring attached only at one end...can't apply any force.

Comment: @Steven. Yes this seems to be something to do with the 'glue' concept. Someone else commented and suggested \vspace*{vfill} as well (and then strangely removed it; it did work). I think I need to understand the concept of 'glue' in TeX.

Comment: Once you get the basic concept, it is still complicated.  See discussion in TeXbook pp.71-72 on the various infinities of glue.  Some glue is more infinite than others.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64756/what-is-glue-stretching  I have a paper copy of the TeX book at home, but link above does seem to go into it.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `\mbox{ }` before `\vfill`.